# Apache Axis2 throws NoSuchMethodError when trying to hit web service?

Tags: web-services, apache, exception, apache-axis

I am trying to hit the following web service with axis2:  http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

I have Axis2 locally, and I generated my classes by downloading the wsdl to my local drive and running:

```
./wsdl2java.sh -uri geoipservice.wsdl -p geoip -d xmlbeans -s -o geoip
```

This produced a build directory with a build.xml file in it, which i then ran "ant" in, and it produced a client jar in the libs folder.

I dropped this jar onto my classpath, and then I tried to hit the service using the following code:

```
GeoIPServiceStub stub = new GeoIPServiceStub("http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL");
GetGeoIPDocument req = GetGeoIPDocument.Factory.newInstance();
GetGeoIP gic = req.addNewGetGeoIP();
gic.setIPAddress("74.125.91.105");  // google.com
GetGeoIPResponseDocument resp = stub.getGeoIP(req);
System.out.println(resp.getGetGeoIPResponse().toString());
```

Things seem to run at first, and I see the results coming back in the syslog, but before it finishes it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLParserWrapper;Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMElement;Z)V
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:52)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:795)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching(OMElementImpl.java:765)
at geoip.GeoIPServiceStub.fromOM(GeoIPServiceStub.java:767)
at geoip.GeoIPServiceStub.getGeoIP(GeoIPServiceStub.java:325)
```

I've googled all over and haven't been able to find what is causing this.  Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get NoSuchMethodErrors if your compiler used a different class definition (during compilation) to create your .class file then the jvm has at runtime.

In your case, it misses the constructor for  `org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMStAXWrapper(org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLParserWrapper, org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement)`

It probably means you have the wrong org.apache.axiom library somewhere on your classpath.

Comment: you sir, are correct.  i had an older version of the axis2 framework on my classpath than the one I used to compile my client jar.  i upgraded the jars on my classpath and they were then the same version.  thank you very much, I spent an hour on that, but now I know for future reference