# Apache axis2/axiom NoSuchMethodError

Tags: websphere, apache-axis, rad, nosuchmethoderror, axiom

Using RAD v7 with WebSphere AS v6.1, I am receiving the following;

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory;

Other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802883/apache-axis2-throws-nosuchmethoderror-when-trying-to-hit-web-service) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RAMPART-372)) have indicated that this is due to conflicting jars. I have installed the latest RAD/WS fixpack, made sure I'm using only one version of axis2 (v1.6.2) & axiom-api (v1.2.13), cleaned & built my workspace multiple times and made sure the correct jars are being deployed. I have also tried setting the WAS class loader policy to "parent last".

My question: Is there any reason other than conflicting jar versions that would cause this problem?

Longer error:

> WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[EOEServlet]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory()Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMMetaFactory;
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:150)
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:133)
>       at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:104)
>       at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:590)
>       at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:90)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.(ServiceClient.java:144)

Comment: Does this occur on a WebSphere profile that has the Web Services feature pack installed?

Comment: @Andreas Veithen, It does. WebServices Feature Pack v6.1.0.9

Comment: I was never able to solve this problem specifically but I believe the answers provided are comprehensive for anyone who has similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis2 and Axiom are part of the WebSphere runtime in version 7.0 and above, as well as in version 6.1 with the Web Services Feature Pack installed. They provide the JAX-WS implementation in WebSphere and their classes are visible to applications. That causes conflicts with applications that package their own versions of these libraries. To solve this problem, you need to switch the class loader policy to parent last.

Note that in some cases this may not be enough and you need to make some additional changes as described here:

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, Axiom v1.2.13 is indeed the correct version to use with Axis2 v1.6.2.

I have WAS 8.5 (vs. your 6.1), and I stopped using RAD Developer a long time ago (I'm usually able to do everything I want/need with Eclipse).

But you might want to look at the WAS class loader viewer to determine whether your app is actually loading the correct .jars:

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2012/12/18/troubleshooting-classloader-issues-with-websphere/

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4, that's good to know. I did check my installedApps directory and verified that the correct jars are being deployed.

Comment: Other suggestions: 1) check your application's WAS class loader policy; set it to "parent last", 2) Does the problem still occur with WAS-only (if you take RAD developer out of the equation)?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to move to a different workspace for the time being. I have tried setting 'parent last'. I'll update the question with these details.

Comment: Please try it, and post back what you find.  Please also look at the [link](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html) Andreas Veithen cited.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers , it is conflicting with web-sphere axis libraries. Create shared library with Axis2 jars and associate them with EAR works for me.
[Steps for creating shared library](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/create_shared_library_and_associate_it_with_the_application_server_or_application_on_websphere_application_server?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with most of posts here. What we did is to add the axis2 (1.6.2) jar explicitly in our lib and redeployed. That fixed the issue.